# passing list <Class> $obj to a mthod in PHP / enabling Type hinting

Tags: php, oop, methods, intellij-idea

Here is my method signature:

```
protected function updateFeeComponent(\FeeComponent $FeeList, $shipment_id, $item_id)
{
    foreach($FeeList as $fee)
    {
       //other stuff
    }
}
```

and I am calling it as:

```
$this->updateFeeComponent($shipmentFeeList,$event_id,$item_id);
```

where `$shipmentFeeList` is  of `@var List<FeeComponent> ItemFeeList`.

How can I pass LIST of Custom object as a parameter to a function?

**EDIT:**

I am using PHPStorm V-9, and was integrating [Laravel-Amazon-mws library](https://github.com/przemekperon/amazon-mws-laravel)
To enable type-hint / Intellicode / Available method list ( whatever you name it), I needed to mention the `variable` type. I fell in to this problem. I know `List` is not something available in PHP, but we often say `List` instead of `Array` because the logic is somewhat the same, store easily accessible multiple items (though implementation and techs differs).

So, my question was about type hinting, at the moment of asking this question, I admit, I failed to think of `array` instead of `List`...

I am neither a native English, nor an expert like most of the guys here..so, I invite everyone to edit this question in a way someone else can get his solution from this question

Comment: Since when does PHP have template types like `List<FeeComponent>`?

Comment: sorry, @var List<FeeComponent> ItemFeeList, thats what the variable type is

Comment: PHP doesn't have lists. It has arrays, but they're not typed. Is that a `phpdoc` annotation?

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the `phpDocumentor` documentation of [types](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html)

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I missed these comments, was trying to fix that at my own..You were right

Comment: and essentially, `List` is a fancy name of array (sticking to basics, not implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the closest you can get to what you want is something like:

```
/**
 * @param FeeComponent[] $FeeList
 */
protected function updateFeeComponent(array $FeeList) {
    // ...
}
```

Where you [annotate with PHPDoc the type](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html) for `$FeeList` as being an array of `FeeComponent` and use [PHP type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) to specify the required type as being an `array`.

In an IDE that supports reading PHPDoc like PHPStorm, this will treat each element in the input array correctly as a `FeeComponent` and provide valid hinting e.g.

```
foreach ($FeeList as $fee) {
    $fee-> // Be provided with properties and methods of FeeComponent
           // in hints here.
}
```

Comment: thanks a billion bro, first comment was quite discouraging, so I created a class member for this list object, set the value and called the function, you approach is definitely, definitely simple...thanks again

Comment: and thanks, I admit my question was not clearly asked....so Voted to close it :P

Comment: @ZaffarSaffee It may not have been extremely clear but I think it's a valuable question, especially with a little bit of tweaking.

Comment: I would request you to re-word or edit it, so that anyone else finding problem may consult it..